# How can I read from the standard error of another program, line by line?

Tags: asynchronous, raku

This program catches all of the standard error from another program, but it sometimes gives me a partial line:

```
#!/bin/env perl6

my $proc = Proc::Async.new('./print_to_stderr');

$proc.stderr.tap( -> $str {
    for $str.lines() {
        put "Captured ERR: $_";
    }
});

my $promise = $proc.start;

await $promise;
```

Using `./print_to_stderr`:

```
#!/bin/env perl6

for ^10 {
    $*ERR.put: "($_): Howdee";
}
```

Just now, I got the following output:

```
Captured ERR: (0): Howdee
Captured ERR: (1): Howdee
...
Captured ERR: (6): Howdee
Captured ERR: (7): Howde
Captured ERR: e
Captured ERR: (8): Howdee
```

As you see, for item `7`, the standard error was broken up between two different `tap`s. But I'd like it to wait and give me a whole line.

---

Update: This was reproducible for me using `Rakudo Star 2017.04`, but this isn't an issue in [`Rakudo Star 2017.07`](http://rakudo.org/2017/07/24/announce-rakudo-star-release-2017-07/) as pointed out by Elizabeth Mattijsen below.

Comment: Push it into another variable, and print it when there is a newline in that variable would be what I would try first.

Comment: Which version of Rakudo Perl 6 are you using?  I cannot reproduce this issue.  In any case, `Supply.lines` should *not* give you incomplete lines.  So if this is happening on the most recent version of Rakudo Perl 6, this should be reported as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Rakudo Perl 6 are you using? I cannot reproduce this issue. In any case, `Supply.lines` should not give you incomplete lines, ever. So if this is happening on the most recent version of Rakudo Perl 6, this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in the latest version either. Thanks for pointing out the obvious thing that I _thought_ I'd checked. My `.bashrc` was still loading the older Rakudo Star environment module.